# What to do about homework and project questions?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a lot of these floating around recently and was wondering how other people approach these questions. When someone states they are working on a project or homework and need help what do you do if they have provided some code ? Some really bad code ? No code at all ? I want to help but I don't want to give them the answer/code. What do you guys do for these ?

Comment: [MSE duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: It's probably safe to assume that the majority of questions are from people who are working on a project or homework, right? So why treat it differently if they state that?

Comment: Its about the question, not about the person or what he/she is doing. You answer questions that are fit for SO, most homework/project questions absolutely are not.

Answer (score 7):

You're not *just* answering for the student.  You're answering for *everyone* that comes across that answer.

If you feel that you can successfully answer the question without needing to go into a lot of technical detail, then more power to you.

Their question should still be held to the standards of the site and be clear, concise, and on-topic.  If any of those fail, you should point them out and alert the OP.

Answer (score 3):

**homework**

- If it is a copy paste set of assignment requirements downvote, vote to close as too broad, and move on.
- If it is a code dump along with a set of requirements with no explanation, downvote and vote to close as "off topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."
- If it is clearly a homework problem but it includes an MCVE and shows what was tried, what was expected, and what happened that didn't work, it can be answered so long as it isn't a duplicate or a one off version of a canonical post somewhere (which they often are).

99 times out of 100 you will find that these questions fall into the first two bullet points. On the rare occasion a student managed to take their assignment, attempt to solve it, got stuck and then posted an example of where they got stuck with what they didn't understand, then there is no problem with helping them there. That is however, the 1%.

**projects**

This is essentially the same as homework. Often the project is just a set of requirements, so downvote and vote to close as too broad.

Less common are the projects which show the entire piece of code being worked on with the very vague description of something breaking. These can be downvoted and closed as either unclear or the debugging reason shown above.

However, where projects greatly differ are the MCVE category. Often professionals or enthusiasts working on their projects will produce a nice narrow example - which is to say the percent of these that have actual examples is significantly higher. This is my favorite type of question because I think these types of questions are what make the site shine. I tend to upvote these if I feel they are in a domain I am familiar with and are capable of being answered in a reasonable scope.